# Возникла проблема с задачкой на c++

Tags: c++

Задача:

> В результате исследований было установлено, что искусственный
>   заменитель сахара, обычно используемый в малокалорийном лимонаде,
>   вызвал смерть лабораторной мыши. Ваш друг очень хочет похудеть, но не
>   может отказать себе в лимонаде. Поэтому он решил выяснить, сколько
>   лимонада можно выпить, не опасаясь летального исхода. Напишите
>   программу, отвечающую на этот вопрос. На входе ее задается количество
>   заменителя сахара, смертельное для мыши, вес мыши и вес человека. Для
>   безопасности указывается не нынешний вес человека, желающего похудеть,
>   а тот вес, который он считает для себя нормальным. Предположим, что
>   лимонад содержит 0,1% сахарозаменителя. Присвойте этому числу (которое
>   можно выразить как значение 0.001 типа `double`) имя, используя
>   квалификатор `const`.

Вот мой код, и видимо я что-то упускаю, ибо с цифрами какой-то бардак

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    const double SWEETENER = 0.001;
    double dead_for_mouse;
    double weight_of_mouse;
    double weight_of_human;
    double dead_mouse;
    double danger_for_human;

    cout << "Введите кол-во заменителя сахара,\n"
         << "смертельное для мыши в граммах" << endl;
    cin >> dead_for_mouse;

    cout << "Введите вес данной мыши в граммах" << endl;
    cin >> weight_of_mouse;

    cout << "Введите вес человека в килограммах" << endl;
    cin >> weight_of_human;

    //смертельно для мышки
    dead_mouse = weight_of_mouse/dead_for_mouse;

    //смертельная доза на 1 килограмм товарища
    danger_for_human = (dead_mouse*1000)*weight_of_human * SWEETENER;
    cout << "Смертельная доза = " << danger_for_human;

    cout << "А для безопасности лучше выпить не более " << (danger_for_human * SWEETENER * 0.75);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Название (заголовок) - как маяк... Ваше название - потухший и невидимый маяк. Надо бы изменить.

Comment: Нужно еще подробнее объяснить `"цифрами какой-то бардак"` ибо на описание проблемы слабо тянет

Answer (score 3):

Ну давайте считать... Если вес мыши `weight_of_mouse`, а смертельная доза `dead_for_mouse`, то доза на 1 грамм - `dead_for_mouse/weight_of_mouse`. Человек весит `weight_of_human*1000` грамм, так что его доза - `weight_of_human*1000*dead_for_mouse/weight_of_mouse`. Лимонада нужно в `1/SWEETENER` раз больше. Итого -

```
weight_of_human*1000*dead_for_mouse/weight_of_mouse/SWEETENER
```

Вот и все.

```
cout << "Введите вес человека в килограммах" << endl;
cin >> weight_of_human;

cout << "Смертельная доза = " << weight_of_human*1000*dead_for_mouse/
                                 weight_of_mouse/SWEETENER << endl;

cout << "Но лучше выпить не более " << weight_of_human*1000*dead_for_mouse/
                                       weight_of_mouse/SWEETENER * 0.75 << endl;
```